# what formula to use in excel when trying to subtract

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtraction

I have a list of numbers that i need to subtract to 60 when the number is greater than 60. is there any one here knows on what formula to use and how for me to do this????

for example:

61    =    1

75    =    15

52    =    52

using the needed formula this should be the result

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` condition.

The syntax for the Microsoft Excel `IF` function is:

```
IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

**Formula**

```
=IF(A1>60,A1-60,A1)
```

[Test link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=57D91AD56FC9B7D9%21804)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is number of seconds or minutes, and you want to clip it at 60 to wrap it around.   This will do it:

```
=MOD(A1,60)
```

Otherwise use the If function like Ullas indicated above.